# Meteor on Windows 10

Tags: windows, meteor

I'm trying to run my first app on Meteor but keep getting the error message below... Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

```
C:\Users\tope\image_share>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\tope\image_share ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.

C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe: {"killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null}
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
    at findMongoPids (C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:120:16)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:236:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:360:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:612:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:712:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:670:10)
    at C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-all.js:199:26
    - - - - -
    at C:\Users\tope\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:73:24
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:662:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that tasklist.exe is not on your PATH. I think it is in c:\windows\system32.